# Sending an automated Ctrl+D within GDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, gdb, gdbserver, gdb-python

I have a Python program that is feeding `JSON` input to a binary running in `GDB` which then reads that input using the C function `fread()`.

The problem is that `fread()` needs a `EOF/Ctrl-D` to stop reading but the JSON input I am passing to the binary in `GDB` are strings so the binary just hangs waiting for more input or a `Ctrl-D`.

I have red that apparently there isn't a way to pass an `EOF` instruction using Python. Is there a way to define an instruction in `GDB` that sends an `EOF` to the binary instead maybe?

If this was possible I could then trigger that instruction in Python after I send the input.

I am not sure if something like this is possible in `GDB` using the 'define' feature.

Thanks

Comment: How do you pass the input to GDB, and then to the program?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sent the generated JSON, close the file descriptor to signal EOF to your C program.

If your generator in written in Python, you should just be able to call `f.close()` on the file object you wrote the JSON string to. If that is stdout, `sys.stdout.close()` should do the trick. I would suggest posting the source of your generator program if you want an exact answer.

Comment: Thanks, don't mind posting source but just to clarify, the Python script isn't interacting directly with the C program. The C program is running within GDB to monitor its operations and the Python script is passing instructions and input to GDB which is then passed by GDB to the C program. I am not sure if what you're suggesting would work in this scenario.